# d3 select all creating charts has bug where value line is missing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using D3 and trying to create multiple copies of the same chart. I am using d3.selectAll and classes, so I am not sure what the problem is. What it displays is the chart working once, but the next chart duplicate is missing the value line but has axes.

Here is a gist of what I am dealing with: https://gist.github.com/pebblexe/b5e94eee3f0b35a601732371511ec460

Thank you!

Comment: Before asking, please read [ask] and how to provide a [mcve]! As it is now, it is a very poor question unlikely to win you over many friends...

Comment: As a hint: You are binding only one set of data values, hence only one line will be generated. When doing `.data([dataParsed, dataParsed])` instead of just `.data([dataParsed])` you will end up with two lines plotted. Have a look at this [demo](http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/0ad4ec96ee7fbd73320403871174a236).

Comment: altocumulus - is there a way to chart a large number of the same graph without repeating the element constantly?

Comment: The key to one or possibly even more viable solutions to your problem is in my first comment, not in the second one. Why do you expect anyone to put more effort into this than you do yourself?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use `.datum(dataParsed)` instead of `.data([dataParsed])`.  This will bind the data to each element in the selection.

Comment: Thank you! That was the answer I was looking for. I wish I could upvote your answer but I don't have an appropriate ranking.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm not sure what those downvotes are about.